# How to move a few objects together to the left and still collide with ball?

Tags: sdk, coronasdk

I got a few tower like things that a ball can jump on them.
The problem is that I can't make the towers move like +5 to left and still be collided.
Can someone help me?

`CODE`

```
_G.mainGroup = display.newGroup()

local rect=display.newRect( 200, 400, 100, 100 )
    physics.addBody(rect, "static", {density= 3,friction= 0.2})
    mainGroup:insert(rect)

-- timer.performWithDelay(1, function(e)
    -- mainGroup.x = mainGroup.x - 4
    -- end, 0 )
```

I tried this in my code. and the rectangle moves without collison with a ball but it leaves behind a invisible replica which has collision becoz a ball is able to bounce on it.

Comment: Please post what you have tried till now?? I mean the code

Answer (score 0):

You should use kinematic objects instead of static objects. Static objects are used for objects which should stay stable for a long time. Kinematic objects can be stable in small times.

Comment: it is the same. it moves but leaves behind an invisible replica.